# Converting columns to rows in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with two columns first_name, last_name, with one row as john mathew. I want result as john in one row and mathew in next row.

```
FNAME   LNAME
-------------
JOHN    METHEW
```

Result as

```
Name
-----
JOHN
METHEW
```

In short want to convert column to rows.

Comment: Please search a little on this site, and you will definitely get your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name
  FROM pivot_test
UNPIVOT ( name FOR origin IN (fname, lname) )
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2f780/7)

Answer (score 0):

```
create table 

tb(fname varchar2(10),lname varchar2(10));

insert into tb values('JOHN','METHEW');

select fname || chr(10) || lname as name from tb;

NAME                
---------------------
JOHN                  
METHEW
```

Comment: This will just concat them.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT fname
  FROM tb
UNPIVOT ( fname FOR origin IN (fname, lname) )